# Find the matrix of a transformation over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields

Let $V = \{\ p\ \in\ \mathbb{F}_2[x]\ \ \ |\ \ \deg(p)\ \leq\ 4\}$  be the vector space of polynomials with degree no greater than 4 and with coefficients in the finite field $\mathbb{F}_2$. Consider the linear map given by differentiation:
$$D: \ V \to V$$
$$p(x) \to  \frac{dp}{dx}$$
Write down the matrix of $D$ with respect to the standard monomial basis $1,\  x,\ x^2,\ x^3,\ x^4 $ of $V$

Without thinking about the field $\mathbb{F}_2$ I would do:

$D(1)=0=0\cdot 1+0\cdot (x)+0\cdot (x^2)+0\cdot (x^3)+0\cdot (x^4)$
$D(x)=1=1\cdot 1+0\cdot (x)+0\cdot (x^2)+0\cdot (x^3)+0\cdot (x^4)$
$D(x^2)=2x=0\cdot 1+2\cdot (x)+0\cdot (x^2)+0\cdot (x^3)+0\cdot (x^4)$
$D(x^3)=3x^2=0\cdot 1+0\cdot (x)+3\cdot (x^2)+0\cdot (x^3)+0\cdot (x^4)$
$D(x^4)=4x^3=0\cdot 1+0\cdot (x)+0\cdot (x^2)+4\cdot (x^3)+0\cdot (x^4)$

resulting in the matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ \end{bmatrix}$$
My question is, how does this change with respect to the field $\mathbb{F}_2$? I am not too confident on how fields work so any extra explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: There's only one good way to take an integer and put it into a unital ring, or field. Putting an integer into $\mathbb{F}_2$ just remembers its parity, so $3 \mapsto 1$, $4 \mapsto 0$, and so on.

Comment: This really depends on what you mean by $\frac{dp}{dx}$. One could, for example define an operator $D$ on $\Bbb F_2$ by setting $D(x^n) = [n] x^{n - 1}$, where $[n]$ is the residue class of $n$ modulo $2$, but the behavior of this map differs from the usual formal derivative $\frac{d}{dx}$ on, say, $\Bbb R[x]$ in important ways. For example, $D^2 = 0$, where the analogous statement is certainly not true of $\frac{d}{dx}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In $\Bbb F^2$, the elements $2$, $3$ and $4$ just "don't exist". In other words, your work is correct once you use that $3=1$ and $4=2$. For completeness: we have $$\begin{align} D(1) &= 0 \\ D(x) &= 1 \\ D(x^2) &= 0 \\ D(x^3) &= x^2 \\ D(x^4) &= 0,\end{align}$$so $$D = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$